# Get DOM reference to Card Body to scroll down

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using [ant.design](https://ant.design/) and trying to scroll the body of a `<Card>`'s body to the bottom. There are 2 common solutions for this.

1. create an empty `<div>` at the bottom of the body and call `div.scrollIntoView()`
2. access the Body element of the Card and call `cardbody.scrollTo(cardbody.scrollHeight)`

The first approach works, but for some reason it also scrolls the entire window down as well, not just the immediate parent div.

I'd like to try the second approach (it works if I use my browser to target the Card Body element) but I cannot figure out how to get a reference to that DOM element inside of my React implementation.

Comment: How about using `querySelector()` targeting that card body element using the general auto-assigned antd classes?

Answer (score 0):

To get reference to the DOM element use useRef() hook to create a ref and attach it to the element using the the ref prop. After render the element reference is stored in divRef.current to interact with

```js
const divRef = useRef();
```

```html
<div ref={divRef}></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this method, but I do not control the individual divs inside of <Card> component in ant design. https://ant.design/components/card/